# Moving laravel project from one server to another

Tags: php, laravel

Basically I had been working on a laravel project for about a year.Later on, I transferred the laravel project to a new pc.

When I try `php artisan serve`, I get:

```
PHP Warning:  require(C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 66

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php
```

Comment: you need to run `composer install` if you did not move the file manually (including vendor)

Comment: Also try to `composer dump-autoload -o` and `php artisan cache:clear`. I also usually do `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan config:clear`, just to be safe

Comment: @N69S what?????

Comment: @N69S it didnt work4

Comment: Did the commands show the exact same error? If not, please show them. Also, I see your project resides in the `xampp` folder which is a webserver itself. What happens when you use xampp as your webserver and visit the web application?